# Clean my Windows 7 of software remains

Tags: windows-7, cleaning

does anybody know a tool which cleans windows 7 out of old folders which remained in C:\ after uninstalling a software.

For example I removed VS 2005 years ago and still have some folders under C:\Program Files\

I am thankful for each advice

**EDIT:**

problem is there is NOT only VS 2005 by Microsoft but also other tools which have remainings in my system. So I know the MS Uninstaller tool which is helpful for MS software, but I need a tool which cleans my system of ALL remaining folders which are not used any more by any software.

Thx for your kind help here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/folder-is-empty-remove-empty-directories-and-trash-files-with-red/

You could try this it will scan your computer for every empty folder, i've not used it but maybe you can tailor it to your needs.

Comment: wow this little piece of software is AWESOME. Exactly what I've been looking for. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Revo Uninstaller (Free)](http://www.revouninstaller.com/start_freeware_download.html) to uninstall your programs. After uninstalling the program with its native uninstaller, it searchs for your disk and the entire registry for probable leftovers (files, folders, registry entries).

Comment: Does it also work afterwards. Because as I said I uninstalled some tools years ago

Comment: @MUG4N: No. One possibility is to reinstall VS 2005 and then to uninstall it using Revo. That was what I did in the past.

Answer (score 1):

After running the un-install s/ware and saving a restore point I've used [everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) file search utility. You can locate all folders/files with say "VS" in their name and delete them. Sometimes involves a bit of detective work and if in doubt leave them alone - what's a few kB between friends!

Comment: sorry but I am not only interested in VS...

Comment: as I said I need a tool which locates all of these folders of any old software

Answer (score 0):

You could start with the [Windows Installer CleanUp Utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer_CleanUp_Utility).  It's a Microsoft utility. Tou cannot download it from Microsoft anymore but you will still find it by googling up for "MSICUU2.exe".

If you need a specific GUID, you can look up the registry entries in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Cycle through all the entries because Visual Studio bundles come as many different products.

For each key you should have a string value named "`Uninstallstring`" which usually translates to

```
MsiExec.exe /X{TheGUID}
```

You can safely paste this entry at the CMD prompt.

Then, once you're sure that the registry has nothing left, and if there are still folders in `c:\Program Files,` you can just wipe them out.

Comment: Thx I already have that tool. Problem is there are not only MS tools I wanna get rid of ...

Comment: @MUG4N, The Windows Installer CleanUp Utility will work for **all installed products**.  Regardless of whether they are developed y MS or not.  Any entry in the registry key I've mentioned can be uninstalled through MsiExec:  Just lookup the entry "UninstallString" String value for that entry.  Even if it's absent you should always be able to type MsiExec.exe /X<theGuid>

Comment: you are right but I have still useless folders under C:\ of software I uninstalled long ago.

Comment: wipe the folders out --> I want a tool exactly for this !!

Answer (score 0):

you should consider ccleaner http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner to remove the unwanted files and folders which software leave behind after uninstallation. And it also clean the registry.

Comment: yeah great software but it does delete only few folders so most of the unused folders still exist after using ccleaner

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the native Disk Cleanup feature? It's what I usually use: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Delete-files-using-Disk-Cleanup